# Heteroscedasticity or Homoscedasticity?

Tags: neural-networks, multiple-regression, random-forest, heteroscedasticity

I'm building a regression model to predict airline prices. I have 11 predictors and close to 80000 data points. Im getting poor accuracy on testing data sets as compared to training. By accuracy, i mean the percentage of predicted data points within 5 % of the observed values. The gap between R2 pred of training and testing also is large i.e 94 and 72 respectively.  Plotting the residual vs fitted value from the training dataset i get a  graph that looks like this

[image: Residual vs Fits]

Also, the histogram plot of the residual looks like a normal distribution to me.
[image: Hitogram]

I used box cox transformation on the response variable i.e price in this case and log on the predictor variable since it is giving a high accuracy.

Q1) At the risk of sounding stupid , is the residual graph plotted for the training dataset or the test set ?

Q2)With respect to image 1, is the graph depicting heteroscedasticity or homoscedasticity ?

If it is heteroscedastic , how do i correct it and improve my regression accuracy ?